# Erro "max res 25, skipping mipmap-anydpi-v26" - Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin-forms, app, visual-studio-2017

estou com o seguinte erro ao executar meu app no Visual Studio 2017:

***max res 25, skipping mipmap-anydpi-v26***

Pesquisei aqui na internet e não achei nada que pudesse me ajudar a resolver. Alguém sabe uma solução ou o que significa?

Vou colocar o print do erro aqui.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: que bom que resolveu, então. Isso não fazia mesmo muito sentido. Eu excluí a minha resposta, já que não explica nem resolve o problema, é improvável que possa ajudar outros. Talvez seja interessante você publicar a sua.

Comment: Você alterou o manifesto do aplicativo Android?

Answer (score -1):

Eu tive o mesmo problema, e parece ser (pelo menos para mim) que o VS não está rodando no modo administrador. Então tente iniciar um emulador com os privilégios , ou resetar o VS e abrir ele com os privilégios do administrador.

Comment: Tentei aqui executar como adm mas o erro persistiu... mas obrigada!